# Add runtime library search paths to pre built binary

Tags: macos, path, binary, package, dylib

I'm trying to package a pre built binary into a Mac OS application bundle and I need to change the dylib and framework search paths for the executable. Unfortunately I can't rebuild the binaries at this point which makes means I have to find a work arround rather than using the correct search paths from the outset. Does anybody know how I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you want a permanent change to the executable. You can get temporary changes using the environment variables described in [dyld(1)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/dyld.1.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/1/dyld). But for a permanent change, you can modify the executable using [install_name_tool(1)](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/install_name_tool.1.html). See [Creating Working dylibs](http://osiris.laya.com/coding/dylib_linking.html) for a good short writeup on how to do it. See the dyld(1) page for the replaceable variables you can use, such as `@executable_path` and `@loader_path`.